# How to get two subnets to talk to each other (foundry and juniper)

Tags: subnet, juniper, switch

I have two switches, one which hosts a 10.130.32.x subnet (which is a foundry switch) and the other which is a juniper SSG and it is hosting a 10.130.30.x subnet.  The users on the .32 subnet cannot communicate with the computers on the .30 subnet.  How would I go about allowing these two subnets to talk to each other?

Answer (score 3):

you need a router between the subnets - the SSG will be able to route between them, but you need to define a route on it and probably add an ACL or 2 since it is a firewall as well to permit traffic to flow between the 2 subnets.

You would uplink the foundry switch to one of the SSG interfaces and define the subnet on the SSG interface.  Then set devices on the subnet on the foundry switch to use the SSG as a gateway.  I assume the other subnet is already defined on another SSG interface.  After both subnets are using the SSG as their gateway, the proper routes are in place on the SSG, and there are ACLs permitting traffic to flow between the 2 networks, they should be able to communicate with each other.

Comment: Thanks! I will be checking into this, sounds like a proper solution to me!

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the base purpose of a router.

Another solution is to unify the two subnets into one by changing the netmask on all the hosts on both subnets. In your case, it should be `255.255.192.0` (`10.130.0.0/18`) to cover both ranges (`10.130.0.1`->`10.130.63.254`), but this could be problematic if you have other switched-computers that should not communicate with them.